# Ansible elasticsearch jinja2 template does not come out properly

Tags: elasticsearch, ansible, jinja2

I have this code in jinja2 that will be constructed in a elastic watch.

The jinja code is:

```
search:
    request:
      indices: "{{_watch_options.input_request.indices}}"
      body:
        _source: "{{_watch_options.input_request.source}}"
        size: "{{_watch_options.input_request.size}}"
        query:
          bool:
            must:
              query_string:
                analyze_wildcard: true
                query: "{{_watch_options.input_request.query}}"
              range:
                '@timestamp':
                  "gte": "{{_watch_options.input_request.timestamp.gte}}"
                  "lte": "{{_watch_options.input_request.timestamp.lte}}"
                  "format": "epoch_millis"
```

The outcome is as following:

```
 "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
        "indices": [
          "log-*"
        ],
        "types": [],
        "body": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": {
                "query_string": {
                  "analyze_wildcard": true,
                  "query": "NodeNotConnectedException"
                },
                "range": {
                  "@timestamp": {
                    "gte": "1535364473991",
                    "lte": "1540548473992",
                    "format": "epoch_millis"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "size": "5",
          "_source": "elasticsearch_log.message"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

But unfortunately the query.bool.must should be set to an array because else elasticsearch cannot do the query_string and add the range.

I reality the input request, respectively the "must" parameter looks like the following. With square brackets:

```
        "must": [
          {
            "query_string": {
              "analyze_wildcard": true,
              "query": "NodeNotConnectedException"
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "@timestamp": {
                "gte": 1535364473991,
                "lte": 1540548473992,
                "format": "epoch_millis"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
```

Can you guys advice id I can declare the square brackets in the jinja template or force ansible to use them in this context ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the yaml shown in your first snippet, then you'll want to prefix `query_string:` and `range:` with a dash and a space at their current indentation level to indicate to the yaml parser they are sequence children of `must:`, like so:

```
    query:
      bool:
        must:
          - query_string:
              # and the rest
          - range:
              # and the rest
```

Comment: It works better @matthew thanks. Another issue appears that query_string has value null although it should just open an curly bracket

Comment: Sure, that's why the comment says "and the rest," I wasn't going to copy and paste your entire example, because it would lose the forest in the trees

Comment: I put the rest :)) like it's in the question